# AppContainer Incompatibility in Protected Mode - Adobe Acrobat Reader

Tags: adobe-reader, windows-10-desktop, pdf-reader

After the latest Windows 10 update [KB4524098](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/4524098) and [KB4525237](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4525237) Adobe Reader suddenly doesn't start properly anymore, and says:

> Adobe Acrobad Reader cannot open inside an AppContainer in Protected
> Mode due to an incompatibility with your system configuration. Would
> you like to proceed?

What actually to proceed? Here are the two options it offers:

> a) Open Reader with the AppContainer disabled inside Protected Mode
>
> b) Do not open Reader due to the AppContainer system incompatibility

in German:

> AppContainer-Inkompatibilität im geschützten Modus

What is actually going on with Adobe? Why is there the need for a "protected mode"? Why is Adobe software not compatible to Windows? And why does the German version of Adobe Reader in its prompt link me to an English incomprehensible ["help" page about protected mode troubleshooting](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/protected-mode-troubleshooting-reader.html)?

[Adobe Reader's error prompt window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IkGr.png)

Answer (score 1):

Could you please check if compatibility settings are applied under Reader shortcut?

1- Find Reader shortcut on the desktop>right-click>Properties

2- Check if the box next to "Run this program in compatibility mode for" is checked.

3- If it is, uncheck the box>click Apply>OK, try opening pdf and see if that works.

Please confirm Acrobat Reader version installed on the machine.

To do so, launch Reader>click Help>select About Adobe Acrobat Reader DC

You may also refer to the following link which discusses the same topic:

https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-reader/adobe-reader-cannot-open-in-protected-mode-due-to-an-incompatability-with-your-system-configuration/td-p/5010848?page=1.

Keep us posted with the results.

Comment: thank you! Since I uninstalled the Adobe software at that time, I can no longer try this solution. I will come back to this troubleshooting thread, after I felt compelled to re-install it.